# Мини-библиотека js

Tags: javascript

Существует ли мини-библиотека js, специализирующаяся на поиске элементов по css-селектору, навешивании на них событий и проходу под DOM дереву? Есть вариант написать свою, взяв за основу YASS, но вдруг такая уже существует.

П.С. jQuery не предлагать по нескольким причинам.

Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: А чем не устроил jQuery? Есть ли какие-нибудь доводы?

Comment: Конечно: большой размер (90+ Кб) и слишком много лишних функций, которые мне не нужны. Плюс, зачастую функции сами по себе имеют лишний код.

Comment: Вы не тот объём смотрите. Правильный: 31 КБ.

Comment: Я смотрю минимизированный негзипованый.

Comment: Функционал jQuery реализован в специальной библиотеке для мобильных устройств http://zeptojs.com/

Comment: Если не нежно тянуть старые браузеры, можно попробовать vanilla.js ;))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел [minijQuery](http://deer.org.ua/minijQuery/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Можете попробовать [собрать из кубиков YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/configurator/). Хотя, наверно, все равно получится больше, чем надо.

Comment: Да, там та же фигня, что и jQuery. Плюс, чтобы собрать библиотеку, надо знать, что в каком модуле находится, а это означает, что надо учиться и этой библиотеке.

Answer (score 0):

sizzle .js  основа jQuery для выбора селекторов.

Comment: Это да, но ведь еще есть и более быстрая YASS.